# Excel - does not show varbinary(16) column from SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2014, type-conversion, varbinary

I have a SQL Server 2014 stored procedure that I've added to an Excel 2013 workbook as a Data Connection.

The stored procedure returns a table defined as follows:

```
create table #rollups
(
    ID_INT_EXT_KEY varbinary(16) not null,
    AS_OF_DATE date not null,
    FOR_MONTH int not null,
    FOR_YEAR int not null,
    FINAL_REPORT_DEPT varchar(100) null,
    PROV_NAME varchar(100) null,
    EXTERNAL_FLAG bit not null,
    YTD_VISITS decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    YTD_CHARGED decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    YTD_PROCS decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    MTD_VISITS decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    MTD_CHARGED decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    MTD_PROCS decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    YTD_VISITS_DIFFLASTMONTH decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    YTD_CHARGED_DIFFLASTMONTH decimal(15,2) not null default 0,
    YTD_PROCS_DIFFLASTMONTH decimal(15,2) not null default 0
);

-- insert data to the temp table
-- select from the temp table
```

I don't have a problem with the stored procedure, it works as intended.

I've added it to the Excel sheet, as an OLE DB Query, command type is SQL with the command text as simply the name of the stored procedure.

It returns the data (a few thousand rows) as expected, except for the first column ID_INT_EXT_KEY (which is a hash of a few of the columns). The column does not get pulled in to the sheet at all, not blank, not hidden. It's just not there. I tried turning on Row Numbers thinking maybe that had something to do with it, but no.

In SSMS the column is there.

This isn't really a problem for what I'm using it for, but it's perplexing and I'm wondering what I can do about it, short of altering the returned table's data types.

Edit:

**Question**: given that I have a stored procedure which returns a table, and one of the columns is a varbinary, **is there any way to get this column into Excel** (using a standard External Data Connection), **without creating or modifying any database objects?**

Comment: A `VARBINARY(16)` is a datatype which is not *visible* or - better wording - *displayable*... There are 16 bytes of something. What would you expect Excel should do with this? You can convert it to a HEX-string (consisting of 0-9 and A to H and mostly starting with `0x` to indicate this. You could convert it to `base64` or maybe cast it to a type of 16 bytes lenght with a rather random value... What should poor Excel do with that value?

Comment: Well, SSMS converts it to a hex string, as you suggested. I had a feeling that it was related to the fact the column contains binary data. This tells me why this happens, but is there anything I can do to resolve it without resorting to modifying database objects? I.e. is there something I can do from Excel to show this column as a hex value?

Comment: I just updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I take *SSMS converts it to a hex string*.

This is not true, it just **looks** like a HEX-string...

SSMS has the same problem Excel would have: How to display binary data? SSMS choses the HEX-string, but the data-type of this column is still VARBINARY...

If you want to get a **real string looking like a hex value** you can use a built in function:

```
DECLARE @Varbin VARBINARY(16)=0x00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF;
SELECT @Varbin AS A_varbinary_VALUE;
SELECT DATALENGTH(@Varbin);

DECLARE @ConvertedToString NVARCHAR(MAX)= sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@Varbin);
SELECT @ConvertedToString;
```

### UPDATE

As your column is `VARBINARY(16)` best should be a direct cast to `GUID`, which is 16 bytes per definition:

```
DECLARE @CovertedToGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=CAST(@Varbin AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
SELECT @CovertedToGUID;
```

You can cast this back:

```
SELECT CAST(@CovertedToGUID AS VARBINARY(MAX))
```

But there's still one question left: Why?

Comment: I did not mean literally converts it to a hex string - I meant "convert" in the context of how the data is displayed. "Why" is irrelevant to the question - I hang onto this hash for various reasons (it's part of the underlying stored procedure, used in joins and for summarizing data, and is useful from time to time outside of that). Like I said, it's not necessary for this particular workbook, but I'm just looking for any way to pull the column in without modifying the SP or creating another db object - in case I do need it in the future, and to satiate my curiosity.

Comment: Ah, I see... In most cases it was much better not to use a SP to retrieve data but to use *inline table valued functions*. In this case you could import this with a SQL statement **from EXCEL** and do the conversion there... You could try to define one more SP, wrapping the first one if you do not want to change this. Excel would display a hex string as it would display a GUID... Without tricking around (VBA!) I don't know any workaround with simple import function...

Comment: I believe I explored the TVF route, and it wasn't feasible because the SP uses temp tables for performance reasons (table vars were very slow). I've learned recently that one can index a table variable, so perhaps I'll revisit the function idea sometime soon. That would be nice because then I could just cast the hash to a varchar in the Data Connection itself.

Comment: @Eric, yes, if a SP uses multi-statement approach, temp tables and such stuff you cannot transfer this into TVFs easily. That's why I suggested a wrapping SP where you first insert the existing SPs result into a table and then create a new output with the proper cast. Anyway: If this answer was helpful, I'd ask you to vote it up. And if it solved your issue, please tick the acceptance check, thx!

Comment: Remember, the question is how to do this without creating or modifying any database objects - maybe I misunderstand you. I will update my question to be more concise.

Comment: @Eric, it was you who was talking about changing this to TVF etc. :-) As far as I know there is no way to let Excel dsiplay a `VARBINARY` coming from a SPs result just by calling it with its name. You can fill a `Recordset` with VBA and fill the cells yourself or you can provide a TVF or you can change (or wrap) the SP to provide a proper type. I think that's it. Don't blame me for missing features :-)

Comment: @Eric, It is possible in Excel to switch the source of the connection to *SQL-Statement*. I don't know, but it might be possible to use your `create table` statement together with `EXEC YourSP INTO ` to fill the resultset into a table first and do the final `SELECT` with a proper cast from there?

Comment: "create table ... insert into #temp exec sp" is definitely a possibility - I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Of course then the issue becomes - how much permission needs to be granted to the user hitting refresh? But that is aside from the question at hand. Thanks for all the suggestions so far!

Comment: @Eric Bettern than a `CREATE TABLE` was - at least in terms of rights - a `DECLARE @tbl TABLE...`